# heroku - choose environment to run migrations?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have set up a qa area in heroku.

For my regular area, for migrations I use:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

What do I use for my qa server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to running the following, specifying the qa version of the application

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app dmplanning-qa
```